# Spring Batch - Different job launcher for different job

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch, executorservice

could you help me solve one problem.

I need to allocate different number of threads for different tasks.

I have jobs:

```
@Bean
public Job printJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step printStep) {
    return new JobBuilder(PRINT_JOB_NAME, jobRepository)
            .start(printStep)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job combineStatementJob(JobRepository jobRepository,
                               Step combineStep) {
    return new JobBuilder(COMBINE_STATEMENT_JOB_NAME, jobRepository)
            .start(combineStep)
            .build();
}
```

and two joblaunchers
for job with one execution thread:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobPrintLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix(TASK_PRINT_THREAD_PREFIX);
    executor.initialize();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(executor);
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

for job with COMBINE_CORE_POOL_SIZE execution thread:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobCombineLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository, @Value("${async.combine-number-threads}") int numberOfThreads) throws Exception {
     TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix(TASK_COMBINE_THREAD_PREFIX);
    executor.setCorePoolSize(numberOfThreads);
    executor.initialize();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(executor);
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

sometimes there are moments when two job launchers interfere with each other and i have next exception -

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict in checking.
  Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1538)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:202)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:178)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy159.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:70)
```

Is it ok to use different job laucners for different jobs, if so, how do I solve the exception problem?

I need different tasks to be shared between executors. The only option I still see is to use critical sections so that job lanchers don't overlap.

Comment: The requirement is not clear to me. Why do you need different job launchers? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve without referring to spring batch?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, I will try to explain in very simple words, I have two services. Calling which should queue up for execution. The first service runs pretty fast and many execution threads can be used for it, the second service runs for a long time and requires a lot of memory, so I run it in one thread. I thought spring batch would be great for creating a processing queue with synchronization through a database.

Comment: Thank you for the update. So if I understand correctly, you have one job that uses service1 (fast) and writes data to a database, and another job that uses service2(slow) that reads data from the database. The database is used a staging area between the jobs. Is that correct?